# Issue with PostCSS Mixins Plugin - How to Upgrade

Tags: npm, postcss

I am unable to use postcss-mixins plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-mixins
My current version is 2.1.0.
I have read about others having the mixins issue (https://github.com/postcss/postcss-mixins/issues/133), so i am trying to upgrade to version 8, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I'm using npm and I've tried the following within this directory: node_modules/postcss-mixins:

- `npm install postcss-mixins~8.0.0`
- `npm install postcss-mixins8.0.0`
- `npm install postcss-mixins@8.0.0`
- `npm update postcss-mixins`

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Our codebase uses an internal version of npm. Once i figured this out, i just replaced 'npm' with 'internal-build-command' and it worked!

```
internal-build-command install postcss-mixins@8.0.0
```